# sql select max date before now

Tags: mysql

I got table where I have dates that might be higher than now(). I want to get maximal lower than now() date with corresponding row. I tried to first get dates before now() and then get max from them.

On my own I come up with:

```
select sub.*,MAX(sub.DATE)
From (
  SELECT s.id_series,s.name,e.title,e.DATE
  FROM episodes e
  JOIN series s ON s.id_series=e.id_series
  WHERE e.DATE < now()
) as sub
JOIN episodes ep on  sub.id_series=ep.id_series
GROUP BY sub.name;
```

I'm getting only correct max date but corresponding row is wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rest of the values too it's easiest to use `exists`:

```
SELECT s.id_series,s.name,e.title,e.DATE
FROM episodes e
JOIN series s ON s.id_series=e.id_series
WHERE e.DATE < now() AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM episodes e2
  WHERE e2.id_series = e.id_series AND e2.DATE > e.DATE AND e2.DATE < now()
)
```

If there is no value bigger than the currently selected one and smaller than now(), then it is the biggest value before now().

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why didn't you use max() function?

Comment: Because max is an aggregation function, so to use it correctly you have to use group by. But when you group by id_series (or name) then only the value of id_series and max(e.date) are chosen. You can add more columns, but you would need to put an aggregation function on each, but there is none that says take the same row as to the left. In most dialects this isn't possible to add additional columns without aggregation, in MySQL you can but it will just choose an arbitrary row. It's possible to find out the max by grouping and then rejoin the original table to get the rest of the columns.